# Como hacer una suma en un arreglo

Tags: c++, dev-c++

El problema es el siguiente:

Dado un arreglo de  enteros con valores iniciales, deseamos ejecutar sobre él una secuencia de  eventos de los siguientes tipos:

Evento de tipo 0: asignarle  a todos los elementos del arreglo.

Evento de tipo 1: incrementar todos los elementos del arreglo.

Calcule cuál sería el estado final del arreglo.
(Si en el segundo arreglo es 1 se le incrementa ese 1 al primer arreglo y asi sucesivamente, pero si es 0 se inicializa el primer arreglo con puros 0)

Esto es lo que yo llevo, pero al ejecutar el programa me da como resultado otra cosa.

```
introducir el código aquí
int a,b;

cin>>a;

int arr[a];

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

cin>>b;

int brr[b];

for(int i=0; i<b; i++){
    cin>>brr[i];
}

int crr[a];

for(int i=0; i<b; i++){
    if(brr[i] == 1){
        crr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
    }else{
        crr[i] = 0;
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cout<<crr[i]<<" ";
}
```

este es el resultado que tiene que dar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema lo tienes en esta parte de tu código:

```
for(int i=0; i<b; i++){
    if(brr[i] == 1){
        crr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
    }else{
        crr[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Explicación: Estas utilizando 3 arreglos `arr`, `brr` y `crr` y en tu ejemplo con los números `a= 5` y `b = 3` los arreglos serían de los siguientes tamaños `arr[5]`, `brr[3]` y `crr[5]`

En tu código estas intentando recorrer de 0 a `<3` (Es decir de 0 a 2 para los valores de `b`) y estás intentando incrementar `arr[]` que tiene 5 elementos, entonces el problema es que no estás modificando todos los valores de `arr[]` con el ciclo `for` que tienes

Para resolverlo tienes que agregar un segundo ciclo `for` que recorra todo el arreglo `arr`. Es decir, tienes un arreglo que recorre `arr` y otro que recorra `brr`

Otro pequeño "problema" es que tienes un tercer arrego `crr` donde quieres guardar el resultado pero al modificarlo con la línea `crr[i] = arr[i] + 1;` siempre vas a guardar el mismo resultado porque no estás incrementando `crr`

Por ejemplo: `crr[0] = 0`, `arr[0] = 1`. Al ejecutar tu línea de código `crr[i] = arr[i] + 1;` entonces crr[0] = 2`pero`arr[0] = 1`no se ha modificado y seguirá valiendo 1, por lo que al hacer tu operación`crr[0]` siempre devolverá 2

Una forma de solucionarlo es utilizar el mismo arreglo `arr` para hacer las operaciones de incremento o "resetear" el valor a 0, de esa forma vas a obtener el resultado deseado

Sección del `for` corregida con los comentarios anteriores

```
for(int i=0; i<b; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
        if(brr[i] == 1){
            arr[j]++;
        }else{
            arr[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Ejemplo completo funcionando:

```
int main()
{
    int a,b;

    cin>>a;

    int arr[a];

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    cin>>b;

    int brr[b];

    for(int i=0; i<b; i++){
        cin>>brr[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<b; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
            if(brr[i] == 1){
                arr[j]++;
            }else{
                arr[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio basatente.

Comment: Solo una pregunta, es que no entendi bien esa parte. Por que dices que arr[ i ] no incrementara. No se supone que en el ciclo incrementaria i pero solo seria hasta 2. Por ejemplo arr[ 0 ], luego arr[ 1 ] y por ultimo arr[ 2 ]. Y hasta ahi quedaria no?

Comment: La `i` si incrementa, lo que no incrementa es lo que tienes en `arr[i]` porque lo estabas almacenando en `carr[i]`